# How to compile the code using clover open version 4.2.0

Tags: clover

i was able to compile my source code and generate the instrument classes(including xxx-clover.war) using mvn clover2:instrument command using clover 4.0.6 maven plugin.
When I tried with clover open source 4.2.0, I wasn't able to execute any clover goals like instrument, clover, setup.

can you someone please tell me how do I compile my project using clover open source 4.2.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `clover:XXX` goals (note there's **no** 2 in clover)

You may also need to update your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file and replace the following

```
<pluginGroups>
   <pluginGroup>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

with:

```
<pluginGroups>
   <pluginGroup>org.openclover</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

There's complete migration tutorial available on [OpenClover pages](http://openclover.org/doc/openclover-4.2.0-release-notes.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reponse @grzlew, after using the clover:instrument coomand i was able to compile the code using clover.

Comment: i had done done POC on a sample we application using maven and eclipse plugin and it worked perfect. But when i was trying to implement on a real time project(in my company) which has 33 modules in it using eclipse plugin (because they are not using any build tool in local) i can see that clover is completely missing one module while compiling and also it is not compiling all the classes in other modules also like interfaces.  Should i do any setting when i compile my project with clover in eclipse(we are using EJB's) in it... please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks

Comment: In case some module is not instrumented by Clover, check how it differs from others. For instance: Is it written in Java? Note that Clover does not support Groovy in IDE. Does it use standard "Java builder" (Project > Settings > Builders) and not "Ant builder" for instance? Do you see "Clover Pre-Java Builder" and "Clover Post-Java Builder" on the list? Do you have Clover enabled in the module? What Clover logging says (you can enable it in Preferences > Clover > Log level)?